# PageRequestManagerParserErrorException - UpdatePanel with custom Page.Render

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a requirement of being able to have dynamic customer-specific text substitutions on every Page.  For instance, I can put "{CarMake}" anywhere in a Page, and it will change "{CarMake}" to "Ford" for our Ford customer, "Toyota" for Toyota, etc. We're doing this with a custom Page.Render function, which will do the replacements on the rendered html just before being output to the client.

A custom Page.Render is essentially the same idea as a Response Filter, and I have already read [Eilon Lipton's fantastic explanation of this error](https://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it), but I am still left confused by why this is a problem in my particular case.

The .ASPX page markup contains, within an UpdatePanel:

```
<p>{CarMake}</p>
```

Then the rendered HTML of the loaded page contains:

```
<p>Ford</p>
```

Then, when the UpdatePanel does a Partial PostBack, I am getting the aforementioned parsing error of the UpdatePanel's response, which appears to contain the correctly substituted text (just like the initial render of the HTML):

```
"1|#||4|2325|updatePanel|UpdatePanelCars|...<p>Ford</p>..."
```

So, if the rendered HTML is exactly the same, why is this causing a problem?  How is the clientside parsing even detecting a difference?

For reference, the code doing the substitution is this:

```
class TemplatedPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
   ...
   protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        base.Render(hWriter); //obtain full html markup, still containing {} at this point

        sb.Replace("{CarMake}", "Ford");
        //other Replacements...

        string alteredPageContents = sb.ToString();

        writer.Write(alteredPageContents);
   }
}
```

I have tried setting EnableEventValidation to false, but that has no effect.

Comment: If the response contains the correctly substituted text, do you need to do the sb.Replace?

Comment: @wazz The sb.Replace is what is doing the text substitutions.  Prior to the sb.Replace call, the rendered HTML output still contains {CarMake}

Comment: Ah. It contains the correctly substituted text, but after your code runs. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your replacement templates `{something}` are inside server side controls like `<asp:Literal runat="server">{something}</asp:Literal>`. A aspx page in its lifecycle passes through many stages and `render` is very close to the end. Before running `render` the page saves `ViewState` which keeps the state (content) of all controls and any changes in server control content result in mismatch of `post`ed request and saved `ViewState`.
The latest moment you can modify the page content is `page_PreRenderComplete` event handler.
Of course, if the page is not `post`ed back (in full or partially) then it doesn't matter.
In fact I use very similar code in many (all) pages but I only reorder control rendering (put `script` to the bottom and so on). Replacements inside `render` resulted in errors and I used some workaround inside `Page_PreRenderComplete`.

**Update to answer comment**

In `Page_PreRenderComplete` you can process page tree to make replacements. Something like this:

```
void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessPageTree((Control)sender); //sender is Page which inherit from Control
}
void ProcessPageTree(Control control) //All server side controls inherit from abstract Control
{
    if(control is HyperLink)
    {
        var hl = control as HyperLink;
        hl.Text = hl.Text.Replace("{{something}}", "something new");
    }
    else if(control is Literal)
    {
        var ltr = control as Literal;
        ltr.Text = ltr.Text.Replace("{{some}}", "something another");
    }
    if (control.HasControls())
    {
        foreach(Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            ProcessPageTree(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This info is really helpful - I didn't know that SaveViewState was called prior to Render.  However, I am still at a loss: what exactly were you modifying within Page_PreRenderComplete?  I have dug through Page's source, and am not seeing a property I can reliably use to reference the Page's HTML output.  Unless you were directly manipulating the Page.Controls?

Comment: @emkayultra See Update. ;)

Comment: I figured this was going to be what you said, and it's what I ended up doing.  I am a little concerned about the performance of navigating the Page's Control hierarchy vs. post-processing the string of rendered HTML, but this will have to do.  Thanks!